# How can I correctly load image/video path from JSON file in React?

Tags: reactjs

current not-working solution

```
render() {
    let path = '../../../public/video/2-twinkle.mp4'
    return (
         <video className={classes.headerVideo} loop muted autoPlay>
                <source src={require(`${path}`)} type="video/mp4"></source>
                Your Browser does not support HTML5 Video!
            </video>
```

Doesn't work??
But if I simply use

```
<source src={require(`${'../../../public/video/2-twinkle.mp4'}`)} type="video/mp4"></source>
```

It works fine, so the path is correct. I just can't use variable name in the require(). Even doesn't work with `${}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To be able to use assets you have to either

> require

or

> import

```
let path = '../../../public/video/2-twinkle.mp4'
```

if you console.log(path) it's a plain string and not an asset.

You should define const path = require('../../../public/video/2-twinkle.mp4') at the top of your file together with your other assets being imported.

> Summary:
>
> > When you simply write a string of the source file without imports/requires you have to make sure that the asset is at that path in your public/server folder. If I can assume that you use webpack, the thing that it does is when you require/import something it scopes it to your build-folder so that it can be reached from your webclient & references it to the correct path like https://domain.example/public/your-asset.mp4
>
> Working solution:

```
import React from 'react';
const path = require('../../../public/video/2-twinkle.mp4');

    class Example extends from Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <video className={classes.headerVideo} loop muted autoPlay>
                    <source src={path} type="video/mp4"></source>
                    Your Browser does not support HTML5 Video!
                </video>
```